# Configure gradle wrapper for all subprojects

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have the following monorepo structure:

```
root/
├─ gradle/
│  ├─ wrapper/
├─ services/
│  ├─ Consumer/
│  │  ├─ build.gradle.kts
│  │  ├─ settings.gradle.kts
│  ├─ Reader/
│  │  ├─ build.gradle.kts
│  │  ├─ settings.gradle.kts
//... more services
├─ gradle.properties
├─ gradlew
├─ gradlew.bat
```

I would like to keep the Gradle Wrapper at the top level. However, when I'm trying to import a single service into Intellij, I have to reconfigure the Gradle and provide gradle wrapper path.
I have seen there is an option to define gradle path by calling gradle wrapper task.
Is it possible somehow to configure the wrapper path as part of `settings.gradle.kts` in each service I have so me or other project members have to remember about changing IDE settings?